# angularjs ani-theme build not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, gulp, bower

Based on the instructions given [here](https://github.com/start-angular/ani-theme/blob/master/README.md)

1. Downloaded zip file of ani-theme project from [here](https://github.com/start-angular/ani-theme/archive/master.zip) and extracted zip file contents to C:\dev\angular\ani-theme-master
2. Installed npm, gulp and bower, here are version info for each tool.

   ```
   C:\dev\angular\ani-theme-master>gulp -v 
   [12:49:20] CLI version 3.9.1
   [12:49:20] Local version 3.9.1
   C:\dev\angular\ani-theme-master>bower -v
   1.8.0
   C:\dev\angular\ani-theme-master>npm -v
   3.10.10
   ```
3. From command prompt change directory to C:\dev\angular\ani-theme-master
4. bower install

   ```
       C:\dev\angular\ani-theme-master>bower install
       bower ui-router#~0.2.13                        cached github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.git#0.2.18
       bower ui-router#~0.2.13                 validate 0.2.18 against github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.git#~0.2.13
       bower json3#^3.3.0                                  cached github.com/bestiejs/json3.git#3.3.2
       bower json3#^3.3.0                                validate 3.3.2 against github.com/bestiejs/json3.git#^3.3.0
       bower angular#^1.3.0                                cached github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.6.4
       bower angular#^1.3.0                         validate 1.6.4 against github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#^1.3.0
       bower es5-shim#^4.0.0                          cached github.com/es-shims/es5-shim.git#4.5.9
       bower es5-shim#^4.0.0                        validate 4.5.9 against github.com/es-shims/es5-shim.git#^4.0.0
       bower angular-mocks#~1.3.0                cached github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.3.20
       bower angular-mocks#~1.3.0         validate 1.3.20 against github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#~1.3.0
       bower bootstrap#^3.2.0                         cached github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.7
       bower bootstrap#^3.2.0                  validate 3.3.7 against github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#^3.2.0
       bower angular-animate#~1.3.15        cached github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.3.20
       bower angular-animate#~1.3.15 validate 1.3.20 against github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#~1.3.15
       bower bootstrap-btn-outline-rounded#~0.0.3                          cached github.com/sahusoftcom/bootstrap-btn-outline-rounded.git#0.0.4
       bower bootstrap-btn-outline-rounded#~0.0.3                        validate 0.0.4 against github.com/sahusoftcom/bootstrap-btn-outline-rounded.git#~0.0.3
       bower jquery#1.9.1 - 3                                                                                 cached github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#3.2.1
       bower jquery#1.9.1 - 3                                                                          validate 3.2.1 against github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#1.9.1 - 3
       bower angular#1.3.20                                                                                        cached github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.20
       bower angular#1.3.20                                                                                 validate 1.3.20 against github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.20
       bower angular                                                                                extra-resolution Unnecessary resolution: angular#1.3.14
       bower es5-shim#^4.0.0                                                                                 install es5-shim#4.5.9
       bower json3#^3.3.0                                                                                         install json3#3.3.2
       bower ui-router#~0.2.13                                                                          install ui-router#0.2.18
       bower angular#1.3.20                                                                                  install angular#1.3.20
       bower bootstrap#^3.2.0                                                                                install bootstrap#3.3.7
       bower bootstrap-btn-outline-rounded#~0.0.3                         install bootstrap-btn-outline-rounded#0.0.4
       bower angular-mocks#~1.3.0                                                                  install angular-mocks#1.3.20
       bower angular-animate#~1.3.15                                                          install angular-animate#1.3.20
       bower jquery#1.9.1 - 3                                                                                install jquery#3.2.1
       es5-shim#4.5.9 bower_components\es5-shim
       json3#3.3.2 bower_components\json3
       ui-router#0.2.18 bower_components\ui-router
       └── angular#1.3.20
       angular#1.3.20 bower_components\angular
       bootstrap#3.3.7 bower_components\bootstrap
       └── jquery#3.2.1
       bootstrap-btn-outline-rounded#0.0.4 bower_components\bootstrap-btn-outline-rounded
       angular-mocks#1.3.20 bower_components\angular-mocks
       └── angular#1.3.20
       angular-animate#1.3.20 bower_components\angular-animate
       └── angular#1.3.20
       jquery#3.2.1 bower_components\jquery
   ```
5. npm install

```
    C:\dev\angular\ani-theme-master>npm install
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

6. gulp build

   ```
   C:\dev\angular\ani-theme-master>gulp build
   [23:42:56] Using gulpfile ~\ani-theme-master\gulpfile.js
   (node:9516) DeprecationWarning: process.EventEmitter is deprecated. Use require('events') instead.
   [23:42:56] Starting 'clean'...
   [23:42:56] Finished 'clean' after 99 ms
   [23:42:56] Starting 'build'...
   [23:42:56] Starting 'jshint'...
   [23:43:01] Starting 'jscs'...
   [23:43:10] Starting 'styles'...
   [23:43:26] Starting 'images'...
   [23:43:26] Starting 'fonts'...
   [23:43:28] Starting 'extras'...
   [23:43:28] Finished 'build' after 32 s
   [23:43:29] Finished 'jshint' after 33 s
   [23:43:29] Finished 'jscs' after 28 s
   [23:43:30] Finished 'images' after 3.1 s
   [23:43:37] Finished 'styles' after 27 s
   [23:43:37] Starting 'html'...
   [23:43:53] Finished 'extras' after 25 s
   events.js:160
   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
                   ^
   Error: styles\main.css: error: couldn't process source due to parse error
   Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
   at transform (C:\dev\angular\ani-theme-master\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\index.js:20:11)
   at Transform._transform (C:\dev\angular\ani-theme-master\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\index.js:68:25)
   at Transform._read (C:\dev\angular\ani-theme-master\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:184:10)
   at Transform._write (C:\dev\angular\ani-theme-master\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:172:12)
   at doWrite (C:\dev\angular\ani-theme-master\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:237:10)
   at writeOrBuffer (C:\dev\angular\ani-theme-master\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:227:5)
   at Transform.Writable.write (C:\dev\angular\ani-theme-master\node_modules\gulp-ng-annotate\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:194:11)
   at Readable.ondata (_stream_readable.js:555:20)
   at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
   at Readable.emit (events.js:188:7)
   ```

Anyone know why this error happens, i see npm install shows an error that Unsupported platform for fsevents 32-bit vs 64-bit. May i know which tool is looking for 64-bit?

Answer (score 1):

hope I'm not too late for an answer:

Try changing the the `if` condition in the `html` task inside the gulpfile like this:

```
 .pipe($.if('**/*.js', $.ngAnnotate()))
    .pipe($.if('**/*.js', $.uglify()))
    .pipe($.if('**/*.css', cssChannel()))
    .pipe(assets.restore())
    .pipe($.useref())
    .pipe($.if('**/*.html', $.minifyHtml({conditionals: true, loose: true})))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('docs'));
```